# Walrus Operator Doesn't Assign Variable?

Tags: python, walrus-operator

Playing with the walrus operator, I have this implementation of merge sort:

```py
def mergesort(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        output = array
    else:
        pivot = len(array) // 2
        left = mergesort(array[pivot:])
        right = mergesort(array[:pivot])
        output = []
        while (l := len(left)) or (r := len(right)):
            if l and r and left[0] < right[0]:
                output.append(left.pop(0))
            elif r:
                output.append(right.pop(0))
            else:
                output.append(left.pop(0))
        
    return output

mergesort([66, 93, 85, 46, 56, 88, 56, 75, 55, 99, 87])
```

But this returns the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_134/1678992391.py in <module>
----> 1 mergesort(array)

/tmp/ipykernel_134/4030760045.py in mergesort(array)
      5     else:
      6         pivot = len(array) // 2
----> 7         left = mergesort(array[pivot:])
      8         right = mergesort(array[:pivot])
      9         

...

/tmp/ipykernel_134/4030760045.py in mergesort(array)
     10         output = []
     11         while (l := len(left)) or (r := len(right)):
---> 12             if l and r and left[0] < right[0]:
     13                 output.append(left.pop(0))
     14             elif r:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment
```

Why isn't `r` included in my for loop, while `l` is?

Comment: Oh shoot, good catch. Updated the code. Try with this function call: `mergesort([66, 93, 85, 46, 56, 88, 56, 75, 55, 99, 87])`

Comment: I added my own answer below, but someone may have a better solution than using `+`. It's kinda unique to this case. What if `r` was a boolean value instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Boolean OR](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) `or` is lazy, so when `l` turns out to be true, `(r := len(right))` doesn't even get executed.

You could use the non-lazy [bitwise OR](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) `|` in this case, although it's a bit of an abuse.

Or just use the [truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of the lists instead of their lengths:

```
while left or right:
    if left and right and left[0] < right[0]:
        output.append(left.pop(0))
    elif right:
        output.append(right.pop(0))
    else:
        output.append(left.pop(0))
```

Btw better use `<=` instead of `<`, so that it's a stable sort as mergesort ought to be.

Addendum: Having fun with laziness:

```
while left or right:
    which = (left or right)[0] <= (right or left)[0] and left or right
    output.append(which.pop(0))
```

Another, note I switched to `while ... and ...` and append the remaining non-empty one after the loop:

```
while left and right:
    which = left if left[0] <= right[0] else right
    output.append(which.pop(0))
output += left or right
```

Or back to your style:

```
while left and right:
    if left[0] <= right[0]:
        output.append(left.pop(0))
    else:
        output.append(right.pop(0))
output.extend(left or right)
```

Comment: Did not know that `[]` is falsey, thanks!

Comment: @Connor Pretty much all empty things are false, see the added link.

Comment: Woah. `output.extend(left or right)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Python gets to the `len(left)` expression and evaluates it as `True`
2. This means it can instantly drop into the while loop without having to check the second statement, `len(right)`, since Python is [lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)
3. *But*, this means that `r` is left uninstantiated, since it wasn't evaluated

Unfortunately, putting extra parentheses around the expression does nothing.

E.g. `while ( (l:=len(left)) or (r:=len(right)) ):` doesn't work.

---

An option for getting around this could be to use `+` instead of `or` since they have the same logical meaning, but `+` requires evaluating the right hand side of the expression.

E.g.

```py
def mergesort(array):
    if len(array) == 1:
        output = array
    else:
        pivot = len(array) // 2
        left = mergesort(array[pivot:])
        right = mergesort(array[:pivot])
        output = []
        while (l:=len(left)) + (r:=len(right)):
            if l and r and left[0] < right[0]:
                output.append(left.pop(0))
            elif r:
                output.append(right.pop(0))
            else:
                output.append(left.pop(0))
        
    return output
```

By the way, if ever you had the same problem with `while X and Y`, where `X=0`, you could use a similar trick as above, but rather than replace `or` with `+` you replace `and` with `*` since `0 * n == 0`. I.e. `while X * Y`

Comment: `any([l := len(left), r := len(right)])` is another option to fix this

Comment: I'd say binary or (`|`) is much cleaner, semantically, and also strict. But I'd add a comment either way, or actually prefer rewriting it. Relying on evaluation order in comparisons is... not that beatiful.

Comment: @phipsgabler wow, didn't know that `|` is strict. Thank you.

Comment: When I started learning to learn programming (in C#, but I also read about other languages), the distinction between `|` and `||` (equivalent to `or`) was always very much highlighted and topic of several exercises... maybe I should feel old, even though I don't think I am :D